# How to "Deep Link" into my application from Google Actions

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I am investigating Google Assistant/Actions on my smartphone and Google Mini smart speaker.

I can open my application OK, however I would like to be able to "Deep Link" into specific activities within my app.

Within in the Actions Console -> DialogFlow I've discovered the pre built App Management Agents

```
Create Action -> Custom Intent -> App Management


App Management
Manage your applications, user controlled settings, and preferences
```

These look good candidates for my use case

However I cannot see how to perform the desired Deep Linking into my app.

Is it not possible to create a Google App action that navigates to an "Inner" application Activity?

I have found this [site](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.deeplink.html)

and attempted to use this code as my "Webhook" but it fails with WebHook error (206) This code looks exactly like what I am after. How do I get it to work though?

Comment: check this : https://github.com/ShwetaChauhan18/ReferralCodeFirebase I have done deeplink in this. May it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google firebase dynamic link library. you will also get code using this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Let me know if you face any issue.